# Connected component identification?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, analytic-geometry

Suppose I give a random 2 variable polynomial relation such as:

$$x^3+y^3=10$$

$$x^2 + 7yx^4 + x^2-15=0$$

Etc...

How do I determine how many individual pieces there are to the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a great question. So great, that it is one of the Hilbert questions. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_sixteenth_problem) for an intro on the subject. It's been solved in some settings, but some parts remain open. It's fun stuff.